# display variable as link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Wordpress and I have set up a shop in woocommerce. I am trying to display brand name as link on product page and I am having difficulties with the code. So far, I have:

```
 <?php $brands = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brand', array("fields" => "all") );

echo "Brend: ";
  foreach( $brands as $brand ) {
       $url = get_term_link( $brand->slug, 'product_brand' );
       echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name '"></a>';

}?>
```

I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''">'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in your code on line 6

I am not able to see what am i doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name.'"></a>';

Comment: `echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name. '"></a>';` use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concatenation here `$brand->name`:

```
echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name '"></a>';
```

This should be:

```
echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name. '"></a>';
```

**Update:**

Also note that, you need to use $brand-name inside the `<a></a>`.

```
echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name .'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';
```

**Update 2:**

Also note that, you don't need to concat `$brand->name` with `$url`, its already having your brand name.

```
echo '<a href="' . $url .'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I tried this and the error is gone. But I can not see any brand name now. Any suggestions? Thanx.

Comment: @Nancy: `print_r($brands)` use this before your loop and share the result

Comment: Ok, did that and the result is

Brend: Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 65 [name] => Nokia [slug] => nokia [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 65 [taxonomy] => product_brand [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) [1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 66 [name] => Samsung [slug] => samsung [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 66 [taxonomy] => product_brand [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw ) )

Comment: check update @Nancy

Comment: Oh that's right.  Thank you!

Comment: @Nancy: if its work for u, dont forget to accept the answer this will help to others.

Comment: I just did. But just another small question - now I see brand name twice in my link like /samsungSamsung instead of /Samsung and when I click no products for that brand shows *because samsungSamsung doesnt exist, but Samsung does). How can I repair this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124511/discussion-between-devpro-and-nancy).

Answer (score 1):

check :

```
<?php $brands = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_brand', array("fields" => "all") );

echo "Brend: ";
  foreach( $brands as $brand ) {
       $url = get_term_link( $brand->slug, 'product_brand' );
       echo '<a href="' . $url . $brand->name .'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';

}?>
```

Comment: please add $brand->name inside the `<a></a>`

Comment: Ok thanks @devpro . now its fine :)

Comment: yes its fine now :) my vote for u

Comment: :) ookk its smart work :P